# double title tags holmepage google - how to correct with htacces?

Tags: .htaccess, joomla, sef

Google tells me i have some double homepage title tags.

for example on:

```
https://www.mywebpage.nl 
https://www.mywebpage.nl/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=12&Itemid=219
```

I use Joomla and all my urls are SEF friendly
I have redirection installed for https and www.
Al works fine..

My htaccess has also the following code

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical   folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

When i enter:

```
https://www.mywebpage.nl/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=12&Itemid=219
```

It redirects to

https://www.mywebpage.nl/?option=com_content&view=article&id=12&Itemid=219

How can i redirect this URL in htacces to go to:

```
https://www.mywebpage.nl
```

Comment: Try to replace htaccess with default htaccess joomla file included in your version package

Comment: The specific  joomla 3.7 entries of the latest version are exactly the same. I only added a redirect rule for directing to https and www. Those rules work  fine.

Comment: nobody knows i guess ??

Comment: Erik but if you have all link in SEF friendly and all relative option in joomla backend enabled, how google read this type of link? I think there was something wrong or you have a link write by "hand" and not from joomla

Comment: You are right Bruno,  There was a lot wrong some months ago. Am just trying to clean up the mistakes and where i can help google understand what to index and what not.  I have cleaned up and redirected dozens of links with help of webmaster tools and htacces. But for some reason the homepage still has double title tags... and i cant get the redirect of the mentioned link to work.